# "Similarity" of two vectors

Tags: vectors

Imagine I have three vectors
v1 = [1,1]
v2 = [.9,.9]
v3 = [.1,.1]

I want to see how closely related two vectors are in both Magnitude and Direction
So consider a hypothetical "similarity" function

sim(v1,v2) > sim(v1,v3).

sim(a,b) will return a value from 0 to 1

I figure i need to weight the importance for both Magnitude and Direction, so for now consider that both Magnitude and Direction are weighted equally.
What would a good approach to this problem be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to measure *dissimilarity* is to use a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) of the difference. For example, if we use the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_norm), we have
$$
\lVert v_1-v_2\lVert=\sqrt{(1-0.9)^2+(1-0.9)^2}=0.1\sqrt{2}
$$
and
$$
\lVert v_1-v_3\lVert=\sqrt{(1-0.1)^2+(1-0.1)^2}=0.9\sqrt{2},
$$
and since $\lVert v_1-v_3\lVert>\lVert v_1-v_2\lVert$ we see that $v_1$ is more dissimilar to $v_3$ than to $v_2$.

Now, if you want to have a measure of *similarity* instead, and have this value lie between zero and one, you could for instance consider exponentials $e^{-\lVert v_1-v_2\lVert}$ and $e^{-\lVert v_1-v_3\lVert}$.

Comment: Alright, So imagine I want to weight the magnitude and direction differently. For example, the magnitude has more of an effect on "similiarty" than difference direction.

Comment: @user2327195: The Euclidean norm of a vector is the same as its magnitude, so it's simple to compare _only_ their magnitudes. If you want to compare _only_ their direction, you could normalise (divide with their magnitude) before computing the norm difference. Now you can make a linear combination of those two methods to suit your needs: $e^{\lVert v_1/\lVert v_1\lVert-v_2/\lVert v_2\lVert\lVert+\lambda\lvert\lVert v_1\lVert-\lVert v_2\lVert\lvert}$ for some weighting parameter $\lambda$ of your choice.